Is there a way to use interruptions in Kotlin like in C programming?
I'm posting here because I haven't found the answer to my question yet after numerous searches. Actually, I would like to know if, in Kotlin, we could interrupt the execution of the main program to run a callback function linked to the interruption and then go back to the normal execution of the main program. So when the interruption comes, the program needs to memorize where it has stopped to be able to resume at the same place after it has finished running the callback function
Your help would be very much appreciated.
I've came across articles on Medium or some websites talking about interrupting threads, about coroutines but there weren't really about what I was looking for.
Here is a pseudo-code of what I would like to do :


Coroutines sound exactly like what you are looking for. Can you show exactly what you’re looking for with some pseudocode?

With coroutines the running code must voluntarily yield for other code being able to resume execution instead. That is different from an involuntary interruption from the outside. Coroutines in Kotlin are cooperative.

You might have problems finding resources because you're using non-standard terminology. "Interruptions" in C? Do you mean signals (which run signal handlers)? If not, can you show the C code for which you're trying to find an equivalent?

@Sweeper I've just edited my post. It's very short because I don't really see how with Kotlin logic I can put that. I used to work with STM32 and handling interruptions on the STM32 is so much simpler, you just need to enable interruption on a specific signal and then edit the callback function linked to it...

Don't try to use "Kotlin logic". Make clarity your first priority. Write it in a way that most clearly describes what you want. From your description, it seems like you want to handle hardware interrupts?

@MSalters Yes, this is what I meant. Thank you for using the right terminology.

Ah, so you mean signals like SIGKILL, SIGINT etc? If you are using Kotlin/Native, you can handle it the same way as your C code by calling the signal function. If you are on Kotlin/JVM, you can technically use sun.misc.Signal but that is a "proprietary API".

@Sweeper Sorry I misunderstood, I didn't mean signals like SIGKILL or SIGINT but hardware signals. And the information on the obstacles is provided by a function for which I cannot see the detailed program. By the way, I edited my post to describe better what I wanted to do.

@Chizu, I think it would be best to provide a small example of C code that demonstrates what you want to achieve. Then we can see how this can be done in Kotlin.

@Chizu Do you target Kotlin/Native or Kotlin in general? In most targets we don't even have direct access to the hardware as it is abstracted. In Kotlin/Native this is probably done similarly as in other languages, but I can't provide any details.

The standard term for this is (hardware) interrupts — you might have more luck searching for that.

@gidds I'm gonna try do my searches with this term, thank you
